# Why is WAMP not displaying any of my files? Just showing a blank white page?

Tags: wamp

I started wamp server and it's only showing blank white pages for all of the files and I am not sure what I should do about it?

It was working before, today I have made no changes to any of the configuration files or anything and there are no error messages being displayed, I've even restated my machine and that didn't change much.
I restart the Apache service and also it's given me an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure you don't have any file named default.php or index.php, as the server will display them before anything else, and you won't be able to choose files from the tree index.

If that is not the case, wamp's htdocs equivalente in apache's xampp is the www directory folder.  Create a folder inside the www directory, say Sites, put some files in there, then run wamp and write `http://127.0.0.1/Sites` (for this example).  You should see the tree directory for your files where you can open them and run your php files.

WAMP didn't run very well in my Windows 7, either, but it does work.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Do u use Skype? If so,
Just log out of your Skype and restart wamp server again. after that  login your skype again. Never login skype before Wamp server started. The Problem is Server port got conflict with skype.
If you're sure with your server configurations then it is possible that it is just a port conflict.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check what port is being used.

left click wamp manager -> Apache -> httpd.conf

Search for this line

Listen 80

If LISTEN is 8080, your url should be `http://127.0.0.1:8080/Sites`

OR change the 8080 port to 80 in the httpd.conf

Answer (score 0):

Edit C:\wamp\www\index.php

Set "false" in this line...
$suppress_localhost = false;

Answer (score 0):

In index.php living in the folder www, edit the line

```
($suppress_localhost?
```

To

```
($suppress_localhost==false?
```

Don't include `;` as it will attract errors. Good luck!